# Read a text file and split the text file by removing delimiters and store it into 2 arrays

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to read a text file and split the text file by removing delimiters and store it into two 1d-arrays (one for **Movie** name and other for **Revenue**)

Example of my text file:

```
Jurassic World=11734562.56
Black Panther@4352749.21
The Revenant}7452893.21
Trainwreck{1547892.45
```

Comment: Define “delimiters”. Any why would you split them into separate arrays instead of one array containing both data?

Comment: a delimiter is the one which separates the values, in my question the delimiters are: " =, @, }, { ". I want to sort the array values

Comment: Paired arrays like that are an anti-pattern. Don't use two arrays. Make one array with a class or a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this code, solve your problem. `Split`function take `char`s and parse with these values. Delimeters are removed your result. If your all text like this (first name and delimeter and revenue), you can select even index as movie name and odd index as revenue.

```
string allText = @"Jurassic World=11734562.56
Black Panther@4352749.21
The Revenant}7452893.21
Trainwreck{1547892.45";

string[] splitStrings = allText.Split('\n', '=', '{', '}', '@');

string[] movies = splitStrings.Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToArray();
string[] revenues = splitStrings.Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which strips unwanted chars.

```
string val = @" Jurassic World=11734562.56
                Black Panther@4352749.21
                The Revenant}7452893.21
                Trainwreck{1547892.45";

string[] lines = val.Split('\r');

string[] movieNameArr = new string[lines.Length];
decimal[] amountsArr = new decimal[lines.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    string[] split = lines[i].Split(new Char[] { '=', '@', '}', '{' });

    // replace new line or space chars with empty string 
    split[0] = Regex.Replace(split[0], @" |\n", string.Empty);

    movieNameArr[i] = split[0];
    amountsArr[i] = decimal.Parse(split[1]);
}

Console.WriteLine("Movie arr: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", movieNameArr));
Console.WriteLine("Amounts arr: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", amountsArr));

Console.ReadKey();
```